# Div growing outside of width constraint despite overflow:auto

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to have a horizontally-scrolling (left-to-right) DIV in a dynamic width table cell (DIVs with *display:table-cell*). The scrolling DIV should be allowed to take up 100% of the containing element without causing it to grow beyond all ancestors' widths. I'd prefer to have a pure markup/CSS fix to this problem, without JavaScript or static widths.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>

#page
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.tcell
{
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#scrollbox
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
}

#scrollcontent
{
    background-color: green;
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

</style>
</head>
<body style="width:100%;">

<div id="page">
    <div class="tcell" style="background-color: teal;">Hello world</div>

    <div class="tcell" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <div id="scrollbox">
            <div id="scrollcontent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L69qJ/

The issue is visible in IE8, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

In this example, the yellow div is being forced to grow beyond it's container (we expect the entire page to be no larger than 500px. See the *max-width* style for **#page**) because the red DIV isn't respecting *overflow:auto* and therefore trying to expand to show the green DIV completely.

Expected behavior: I'd like for the teal and yellow cells to add up to 100% of their parent (**#page**). The green cell is so wide that it's making the red cell expand, which is making the yellow cell expand. It's expected that the red cell use a horizontal (left-to-right) scrollbar instead of making the yellow cell expand.

Comment: You should first add `overflow: hidden;` to `#page`, but I can't succeed to make the yellow box to scroll... =/ Also, "I'm attempting to have a vertical-scrolling DIV in a dynamic width table cell", do you mean horizontal scroll ?

Comment: is this what you are looking for? `http://jsfiddle.net/L69qJ/5/`

Comment: I am having troubles to understand what you want exactly. Could you please rephrase, if you don't mind, your "expected behavior" ?

Comment: @Elfayer I mean left-to-right scrolling. I refer to that as vertical. Sorry if that's not right, haha

Comment: @JeevanJose that is not what I'm looking for. That cuts off the offending content, but still does not keep the scrolling DIV from expanding.

Comment: @Andrew I apologize. I'd like for the teal and yellow cells to add up to 100% of their parent (#page). The green cell is so wide that it's making the red cell expand, which is making the yellow cell expand. It's expected that the red cell use a vertical (left-to-right) scrollbar instead of making the yellow cell expand. Is that easier to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
display:table;
table-layout:fixed;
```

to #page.

There it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/L69qJ/8/

Comment: This is great. Additionally, is there a way to allow the yellow cell to be "greedy" with the parent's width, instead of the teal and yellow cells being even?

Comment: Try to add a new class and do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/L69qJ/9/

Should work even if you resize it.

Comment: searching around for a "greedy" dynamic setup seems to be pretty fruitless, so I guess I'll have to do as you suggest and use a static width. At least the majority of the document remains dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the problem is that you are using table-cells. Table cells inherently take the shape of their children, so if you set something wide inside of a table cell, you can't just add a width to the table cell and expect it to follow that rule. You need to transition to using percentage width inline divs, or floats to achieve your layout.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: The table cells aren't expected to follow any width constraints besides their parent/container. I use table cells because I want the teal and yellow DIVs to add up to 100% of the parent container without providing static widths. Can this be accomplished with your suggestion?